# Azure ICollector Overloaded not distinct instances

Tags: c#, azure, interface, overloading, azure-functions

I have overloaded Azure ICollector Interface for my test classes.

However, when the collector is created and data is added, two collectors initialzed are being treated as a a single collector.

Below is my code for collcetor class.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace ChangeFeedPublisherTests
{
    class TestCollector<T> : ICollector<T>
    {
        public static List<T> Collector = new List<T>();

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            Collector.Add(item);
        }

        public List<T> GetCollector()
        {
            return Collector;
        }
    }
}
```

Two collectors are initialized as below, including my test code

```
        var actualCollector = new TestCollector<String>();
        var documents = new List<Document>();
        Document document = CreateDocument();
        var changedSubdocuments = new List<String>();
        changedSubdocuments.Add("AlternateId");
        document.SetPropertyValue(ChangedSubdocumentsPropertyName, changedSubdocuments);
        documents.Add(document);
        MessageHandler.Run(documents, actualCollector, logger);

        var expectedCollector = new TestCollector<String>();
        var changeFeedMessage = DocumentToChangeFeedMessage(document);
        var cloudEvent = CreateCloudEvents(JObject.FromObject(changeFeedMessage));
        expectedCollector.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cloudEvent));

        var expectedCollection = expectedCollector.GetCollector();
        var actualCollection = actualCollector.GetCollector();

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCollection, actualCollection);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCollection.Count, 1);
```

Run function adds data into the collector.

When the collectors are asserted, both added data are included in both collectors, instead of each of them having one data added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have

```
public static List<T> Collector = new List<T>();
```

It's static, so it's shared between all instances.

Just remove the `static` keyword.

P.S. "Overload" is not the right word here: you "implemented" the interface, or "mocked"/"faked" it.

P.P.S. The easiest implementation would look like this:

```
class TestCollector<T> : ICollector<T>
{
    public List<T> Collector => new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Collector.Add(item);
    }
}
```

`Collector` is read-only, and you don't need a redundant `GetCollector` method.

Comment: can I still access collector without having GetCollector method?

Comment: Just updated the TestCollector<T> class based on your recommendation. However what do you mean when you say its 'read-only'? doesn't that mean the collector list is not modifiable, thus not being able to add item into the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert the messages in this TestCollector, getting the Collector property always returns a new list.

I suggest to modify it like so:

```js
internal class TestCollector<T> : ICollector<T>
{
    public List<T> Collector { get; }

    internal TestCollector()
    {
        this.Collector = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Collector.Add(item);
    }
}
```